# Mass: a form of energy

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass, mass-energy, binding-energy

Einstein's $E=mc^2$ and law of conservation of energy implies that mass is a form of energy, but if it is a form of energy then why can we freely interact with mass while the other forms of energy are so abstract

Comment: Why do you feel you can interact more "freely" with a falling anvil than you can with a lightning bolt?

Comment: How do you interact with mass? BTW, "mass" is not synonymous with "matter".

Comment: Note that the $m$ in Einstein formula refers to *rest mass*.

Comment: @Steeven. In that case $E$ is not the total energy, just a "rest energy". Using *relativistic mass* $m=\gamma m_0$ the kinetic energy is included in $E$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately $E=mc^2$ is both super-famous and usually misunderstood. It is not that mass is a form of energy, but rather that energy has mass (see below for a caveat). If you have an object that has thermal energy, electrical energy, and nuclear force energy, all of those are different forms of energy. Mass is not a separate form of energy, but rather each of those other forms of energy contribute to the object’s mass.

You can convert energy from nuclear energy to thermal energy (e.g. by nuclear decay), and that is a transformation between different forms of energy. But the mass is the same because both forms of energy have mass.

Note also that $E=mc^2$ is a special case for use only when the momentum is 0. The general form, including momentum, is $m^2 c^2=E^2/c^2-p^2$. This clearly reduces to the famous equation when $p=0$, but you can also use this to show that if $m$ is fixed and $p$ increases then $E$ also increases. This is of course linear kinetic energy, so in that sense and that sense only linear KE could be considered a different form of energy from mass. Otherwise it is only energy without momentum that has mass.

Regarding your comment, we can interact with all forms of energy pretty equally, but again mass is not a form of energy.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I thought I covered that sufficiently already in the third paragraph, but I edited to emphasize that further.

Comment: "mass is not a form of energy." Why? Consider the inelastic collision of two particles. The mass of the formed particle will consist of the energies and masses of the original particles. Well, for example, the mass of a proton, which is the some sort of sum of the masses of quarks and their energies.

Comment: @Sergio I explained that already in the answer. If mass were a form of energy then electrical energy, being a different form, would not have mass. Mass is something that energy has (provided p=0), regardless of the specific form of energy. In your example, there will be an increase in some specific form of internal energy, like the EM energy in an excited atomic state. The form then is EM energy and it has mass

Comment: Why even say either "mass is a form of energy" or "energy has mass"? What I have understood when exploring special relativity is that mass and energy are more or less the same thing. Or at least: energy has inertia.

Comment: @md2perpe mass is only proportional to energy if momentum is zero. So I don’t think “more or less the same thing” is accurate

Comment: @Dale. How do you define *mass*?

Comment: @md2perpe the usual way, which is what I already wrote in the answer: $m^2 c^2=E^2/c^2-p^2$. I.e. in words it is the invariant norm of the four momentum

Comment: @Dale. Okay, I could continue with asking for your definitions of $E$ and $p$. But it's better to focus on what I found exploring special relativity: A tense spring has more inertia than a relaxed spring and the added energy will increase by $\gamma$ when the spring is accelerated. Also, even a rather abstract energy flow has a momentum.

Comment: @md2perpe I use the standard definitions for energy and momentum also. I am not defining or using anything in a tricky or non-standard way at all. Your findings are correct and consistent with the standard definition of mass. The statement that they are essentially the same thing is not. Anyway, we are getting the extended discussion warning. If you want to have a discussion please go to physicsforums.com which is discussion oriented

Comment: Mass is a relativistic invariant, energy is not. So it is difficult to say that it is more or less the same thing?

Comment: @Dale. I'm registered at PhysicsForum. Could you refer me to a discussion about this?

Comment: @VincentFraticelli. I realize that my wordings are affected by the use of *relativistic mass* when I learned about relativity. But what I refer to is things like adding energy to a system can increase its mass and that energy has inertia.

Comment: the law states that we can only convert energy from one form to another, however when particle and anti particle pair collide, they cancel each other producing pure energy, so its safe to say mass was converted to energy

Comment: @md2perpe this is a good one: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/energy-mass-equivalence.1003564/#post-6497464

Comment: @justsomeguyontheinternet the issue is that while a single photon doesn’t have mass a system of many photons does have mass. In this case, the system of two photons post-annihilation has the same mass and the same energy as the system of the original positron and electron. No mass or energy was converted, they were each individually conserved. If mass could be converted to energy then the right side of $E=mc^2$ would decrease and the left side would increase and they would no longer be equal

Comment: Of relevance: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/equivME/